# Dev Hub missing in Setup

Tags: developer

I want to enable Dev Hub in my <s>Production</s> Developer Salesforce Org.

I'm in Lightning mode as an Admin. If I go to Setup, and type 'Dev Hub' in the Quick Find box nothing appears.

How can I find this?

**Update 28th January 2018** : My original question stated 'Production' - it was a mistake. Edition is 'Developer'

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this feature is in Beta so availability might not be guaranteed.

Comment: Dev Hub is GA now. You can find it in Setup -> Development

Comment: @MartinLezer I added two screenshots to the question

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande probably I might need a ticket for this. I was able to get a trial Dev Hub with no issues...

Comment: I'm also unable to enable Dev Hub

Comment: @Andrew what edition is your Org? Enterprise/Pro/Developer?

Comment: @Robs - I made a mistake. Checked again and it was 'Developer'. I have updated the question

Answer (score 6):

Dev orgs don't get a Dev Hub. Only prod orgs and Enterprise demo orgs get it.

---

## EDIT (September 2018)

Dev Hub in Developer Edition is available starting with the Winter 19 release which rolls out in October 2018. See [this link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sfdx_dev_hub.htm) for more details.

Comment: Not true see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm

Comment: Read the date. What I posted was true on January 28, 2018. You are referencing documentation for Winter 19 which rolls out in October 2018.

Comment: indeed! cheers.